# How to use SPARQL query to get information within in the rdf:Description in RDF/XML?

Tags: sparql, rdf

For example, how to use SPARQL query to get the zthes:label in Def1-4393574 for the skos:Concept (#4393574). 
Thanks!

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" 
 xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" 
 xmlns:zthes="http://synaptica.net/zthes/">
 <skos:Concept rdf:about="#4393574">
 <skos:prefLabel>A prefLabel</skos:prefLabel>
 <zthes:termNote rdf:ID="Def1-4393574">Def1</zthes:termNote>
 </skos:Concept>
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="Def1-4393574">
 <zthes:label> a zthes label</zthes:label>
 </rdf:Description>
 </rdf:RDF>
```

**UPDATED:** Here is the Turtle version converted by http://www.easyrdf.org/converter

```html
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix ns0: <http://synaptica.net/zthes/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://example.me/#4393574>
  a skos:Concept ;
  skos:prefLabel "A prefLabel" ;
  ns0:termNote "Def1" .

<http://example.me/#Def1-4393574>
  a rdf:Statement ;
  rdf:subject <http://example.me/#4393574> ;
  rdf:predicate ns0:termNote ;
  rdf:object "Def1" .

<http://example.me/Def1-4393574> ns0:label " a zthes label" .
```

Comment: convert the RDF/XML document into Turtle syntax -> write the SPARQL query. `SELECT ?label WHERE {SOMETHING_IS_MISSING_HERE zthes:termNote/zthes:label ?label}` - tutorials as well as documentation is online. In your case the query is trivial, you should be able to solve this if you read a tutorial and just try it

Comment: @AKSW, Thanks for your reply. I tried this: SELECT *
WHERE { 
?p  zthes:termNote/zthes:label ?label .
} it doesn't works... Any suggestions? Meanwhile, why these two are different? <http://example.me/#Def1-4393574> and <http://example.me/Def1-4393574> Could you write a complete version of a query? What I want are the skos:prefLabel and the " a zthes label" . Thanks so much!

Comment: Who wrote your RDF/XML?  I wonder if it's incorrect, given the Turtle it was transformed into, and what you're saying you want to get out of it...

Comment: @TallTed, it is a simplified version RDF exported from Synaptica ® Software.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your data doesn't actually *have* a relation between the zthes:label and the skos:Concept.

The root cause of this is a subtle syntax error in your original RDF/XML file. This line:

```
<zthes:termNote rdf:ID="Def1-4393574">Def1</zthes:termNote>
```

defines a resource with identifier `<http://example.me/#Def1-4393574>`. Meanwhile, this line:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="Def1-4393574">
```

defines another resource, with identifier `<http://example.me/Def1-4393574>`. They are *not* the same resource (notice the missing `#`), so the two definitions are not linked. This particular problem could be fixed by adding a `#` in front, like so:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="#Def1-4393574">
```

This fix would result in the following RDF model (using Turtle syntax):

```
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix zthes: <http://synaptica.net/zthes/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://example.me/#4393574>
  a skos:Concept ;
  skos:prefLabel "A prefLabel" ;
  zthes:termNote "Def1" .

<http://example.me/#Def1-4393574>
  a rdf:Statement ;
  rdf:subject <http://example.me/#4393574> ;
  rdf:predicate ns0:termNote ;
  rdf:object "Def1";
  zthes:label " a zthes label" .
```

It's still a very odd RDF model by the way, using statement reification, but assuming that this is just what you have to work with, a query to get the zthes label for given concept would be something like this:

```
 PREFIX zthes: <http://synaptica.net/zthes/>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

 SELECT ?label
 WHERE {  
    [] rdf:subject <http://example.me/#4393574> ;
       zthes:label ?label . 
 }
```